# Possible inconsistencies in finding the equation of a tangent line to a curve that also passes through a point.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

As the title says, there may be possible inconsistencies in finding the equation of a tangent line to a curve that also passes through a point.

Consider a problem that asks you to find the equation of all tangent lines to the curve f(x) = x^2 that also pass through (5,9). Well one knows that the general equation for a line that passes through a specific point (a,b) is y-a = m(x-b). In this case we have y-9 = m(x-5). We also know that m = f'(x) since it is a tangent of the curve f(x). Furthermore, there is a restriction on f'(x) in that it must pass through (5,9), meaning that f'(x) must = (f(x)-9)/(x-5). Plugging in everything, we have 2x = (x^2 - 9) / (x - 5). Solving, we have x = 9 and 1. Since m = f'(x), we have m = 18 or 2. Then, we plug everything in and we get y = 2x-1 and y = 18x - 81.

Everything seems fine. So far...

Consider a very similar question: find the equation of all tangent lines to the curve f(x) = x^2 that also pass through (1,1). The biggest difference between this problem and the other is this is a "degenerate" case in the sense that (1,1) actually exists on line f(x) = x^2. Using what we have above, we  setup the equation y-1 = m(x-1) and proceed to solve for m like before. We have 2x = (x^2 - 1) / (x - 1) and solving, we have x = 1. We then plug in 1 into 2x and then plug and chug and we get y = 2x-1.

Not sure how you put an image, but if you look on desmos, the line is correct and is a tangent of f(x) = x^2 and also passes through (1,1)

Now this seems fine except for the fact that if we check x = 1 for 2x = (x^2 - 1) / (x - 1), we have 0/0 = 2. My question is why does this nonsense equality still yield a legitimate answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re making a very common mistake, one that’s related to the key error in the classic false proof that $2=1$: When you divided the equation $f'(x)(x-5)=f(x)-9$ by $x-5$, you’ve added a potential division of both sides by zero. The resulting right-hand side ${x^2-9\over x-5}$ is undefined for $x=5$. So, you need to add the condition $x\ne5$ for this transformation to be valid. This tacit condition stays with the equation throughout all of the succeeding manipulations. The solutions to the equation are $x=1$ and $x=9$, neither of which is equal to the prohibited value, so the division and other manipulations of the equation were all valid after all.

In the second case, you divide the equation by $x-1$, so the additional condition is $x\ne1$. Unfortunately, the only solution is $x=1$, so this division wasn’t really valid, as you saw yourself when you plugged this value into ${x^2-1\over x-1}$ and got an indeterminate form. On the other hand, solving this equation as if the division was valid produced the right answer. How come?

Viewed as a function of $x$, the expression ${x^2-1\over x-1}$ has a *removable discontinuity* at $x=1$. The value of this function is equal to $x+1$ everywhere that it is defined and $\lim_{x\to1}{x^2-1\over x-1}=2$, which is consistent with $x+1$, so we can “patch” the function with this value so that it’s equal to $x+1$ everywhere. That’s effectively what you did if you solved the equation by reducing the right-hand side to $x+1$.

Another justification is that the formal polynomial division that reduces the r.h.s. to $x+1$ is valid in the ring of polynomials over $\mathbb R$. The power series for ${x^2-1\over x-1}$ converges at $x=1$, so all is well. You’ll see this sort of thing done fairly often in other contexts, such as finding the sum of an infinite series: you formally manipulate an equation or expression assuming that everything you’re doing to it is valid, and then after getting the answer show in some other way that the derivation was in fact valid, e.g., that the series converges in the right region. (A lot of people skip that second part.)

The issue could’ve been avoided altogether by solving the original equation in a different way. Instead of dividing $f'(x)(x-x_0)=f(x)-f(x_0)$ by $x-x_0$, move everything to the left and simplify: $$2x(x-1)=x^2-1 \\ 2x(x-1)-x^2+1=0 \\ x^2-2x+1=0 \\(x-1)^2=0.$$ Every step of that solution is valid for all $x$. Another possibility is to factor the r.h.s. into $(x+1)(x-1)$ first, then move everything to the left and simplify using the distributive law. In some sense, that’s equivalent to dividing both sides by $x-1$, but without the potentially illegal division.

Comment: Well if there is a tacit condition that x =/= 1, then how come using x as 1 still yields the correct answer?

Comment: @TypicalHighschooler Well, how did you go about solving your equation $2x=(x^2-1)/(x-1)$ for $x$? I’m going to guess that you started out by multiplying it by $x-1$, which is also only valid for $x\ne1$ as otherwise you’re multiplying both sides by zero. Fortunately that undid the potential division by zero that got you this equation in the first place. This hidden division by zero is exactly the same kind of error that’s the key wrong step in the classic false proof of $2=1$.

Comment: @TypicalHighschooler now, as it happens, $(x^2-1)/(x-1)$ is equal to $x+1$ everywhere that it’s defined and its limit as $x\to1$ is $2$, so it has what’s called a *removable discontinuity* there. In practice, you can often ignore the discontinuity and operate as if the expression is defined there with value equal to its limit, as is the case here.

Comment: I see. Then is it correct to say that earlier, when I did  2x = (x^2 - 9) / (x - 5) I really did 2x = lim (x^2 - 9) / (x - 5)? If so, that begs the question: Why would I even be concerned with limit on the RHS when all I am doing is finding a general equation for the slope between (x,x^2) and (5,9) for an arbitrary x?

Comment: @TypicalHighschooler No. In that case, the added restriction was $x\ne5$. Since the neither value of $x$ that you eventually came up with was $5$, the division by $x-5$ and all of the following manipulations were valid—you avoided the discontinuity—so limits didn’t come into play there. (BTW, that not “begging the question,” which is actually a type of circular reasoning. Another *very* common error ;))

Comment: @TypicalHighschooler Updated my answer to cover these questions, too.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation and all the help. Appreciate it a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Because
$\lim_{x \to 1} \dfrac{x^2-1}{x-1}
=\lim_{x \to 1} (x+1)
=2
$.

Comment: But right now it is the RHS of the equation that gives us a nonsense answer. I agree that f'(x) should be two, but that doesn't explain the 0/0 from (x^2 - 1) / (x - 1)

Comment: It's not a nonsense answer. If you get an indeterminate, the next step is to look at the limit.

Comment: That makes alot of sense. Thanks!